# Get rtsp stream from Axis camera on Android

Tags: android, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to show rtsp stream from an Axis camera into a mediaplayer object, here the code:

```
public class Rtsp extends Activity {

String PATH_TO_STREAM = "rtsp://192.168.131.21/mpeg4/1/media.3gp";

private VideoView video;
private MediaController ctlr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    ctlr=new MediaController(this);
    ctlr.setAnchorView(video);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(PATH_TO_STREAM);
    video.setMediaController(ctlr);
    video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    video.start();
}}
```

I can correctly stream with the VLC but I get this error with Android:

```
02-10 11:58:07.071: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResourceConfiguration
02-10 11:58:07.101: ERROR/MediaPlayer(432): error (1, -16)
02-10 11:58:07.101: ERROR/MediaPlayer(432): Error (1,-16)
02-10 11:58:07.101: DEBUG/VideoView(432): Error: 1,-16
02-10 11:58:07.121: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
02-10 11:58:07.711: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43bfce30 (uid=10007 pid=106)
02-10 11:58:12.902: DEBUG/dalvikvm(106): GC freed 2635 objects / 150552 bytes in 314ms
```

Any hint? Thanks

Comment: Were you able to do this at the end? I'm trying the same thing basically, any info will be aprreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Call `video.requestFocus();` before `video.start();`. I guess it will make your code run.